# Cut/Slice UiImage using coordinations

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, crop, slice

I have an image that I want to slice like the photoshop knife tool using two or more coordinations on the image. I then want to erase the top portion of the image and replace it with a transparent background. If anyone can point me in the right direction or has code that can do it I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try using a UIGraphicsContext. Here is a similar question, I hope it helps.

[Slicing up a UIImage on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248667/slicing-up-a-uiimage-on-iphone)