# How to retrive single image from png file in iphone

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I can access image's by using  `[UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfPng.png"];` if I have a single image in a `.png` file. But if we are having a multiple images in a `.png` file, how do we access sub images from a single UIImage ?

[image]

This is the single `.png` file. If  i wanted to get the red button image or any other button image how can I do this.

Comment: You can't get it out without doing some image processing fx using Core Graphics.

Comment: a png contains only one image.

Comment: @MarcinKuptel Please give me some more idea about that

Comment: @Apple Did you mean  to say part of the image???

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I know that but If .Png having multiple image then how to separate that through coding.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to do it programmatically? How about creating a few separate images in a graphics editor?

Comment: @VinayakKini Yes... As in any button from the given image.

Comment: What you need is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248667/slicing-up-a-uiimage-on-iphone

Comment: @MarcinKuptel I already suggest that but some some ppl don't want to do this, they told me this is possible.

Comment: Yes you can separate. But end of the day you will find yourself created another project. You need to check each pixel and then cut the image from the pixel where you get whiteColor. Store it, create a new image. If you want to implement something like this...!!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Hope they are not saying to do so... otherwise its better to leave the idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to do is to create a clipped UIImage from a section of your current image. I usually do it this way, changing the clip rect each time. Where srcImage is your original image.

```
//Set the clip rectangle
CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

//Get sub image
CGImageRef drawImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(srcImage.CGImage, clipRect);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:drawImage];
CGImageRelease(drawImage);
```

Comment: So in this case I have to give the frame of each button to clip the image of that.

Comment: Yes, which you would use for the upward state. Same as loading a single UIImage for each pressed state here you would load your sub image then assign it to a UIButton. It is worth noting that there is little point using texture atlas's when using UIImages it wont save you any memory or disc space like it would if you where using OpenGLES. So you might be making a lot of work for yourself for no reason here.